I am unable rebuild Android module in new Flutter version 3.19.6 in new version of Android Studio Jellyfish | 2023.3.1
I had install newest Android Studio Jellyfish | 2023.3.1 and then install flutter version  3.19.6 in windows10. And I try to create sample flutter project. I am able to create project but I try to build android module to add permission and then close module.Then afterwards I add new dependencies and try to flutter pub get and try to open module it not opening up but suddenly it disappear up.
Can please tell which java Jdk is need?And which android gradle dribution version is need update with android APT assistance with Kotlin version prompt of 1.9.0 version?
